# Probabilistic prediction based on occurrence frequency

Tags: python, pandas, probability, prediction

I have a time series of rainfall from 2011-2013 where rainfall data in 1 (no rain) and 0 (rain) format. The original data interval is 1 hour and from daily at 10 am-3 pm. I don't want to predict the rainfall for 2014 but I want to predict the chance of rain for the whole year of the same time interval based on the occurrence of 1 or 0 in the rainfall column. Currently, I use the following code to predict the chance of rain by counting 1 or 0 appearances:

```
import pandas as pd
 
b = {'year':[2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,
             2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,
             2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013],
     'month': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
     'rain':[1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]}

b = pd.DataFrame(b,columns = ['year','month','rain'])

def X(b):
    if (b['month'] == 1):
        return 'Jan'
    elif (b['month']==2):
        return 'Feb'
    elif (b['month']==3):
        return 'Mar'
    elif (b['month']==4):
        return 'Apr'
    elif (b['month']==5):
        return 'May'
    elif (b['month']==6):
        return 'Jun'
    elif (b['month']==7):
        return 'Jul'
    elif (b['month']==8):
        return 'Aug'
    elif (b['month']==9):
        return 'Sep'
    elif (b['month']==10):
        return 'Oct'
    elif (b['month']==11):
        return 'Nov'
    elif (b['month']==12):
        return 'Dec' 

b['X'] = b.apply(X,axis =1)

mask_x = (b['X']=='Jul')

mask_y = b['rain'].loc[mask_x]

mask_y.value_counts()
```

I think this method would not work for large datasets, can someone suggest me an efficient and robust way to predict rainfall from such kind of dataset.

Comment: What about of just using the mean in the same period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data was created by randomly selecting `[0,1]` every hour. We calculated the total and the number of cases by grouping them by time in the date column. Now you can calculate the rainfall rate by total/number of events. I'm following your code to create year, month and month shortened names, but it's not really necessary.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed(20200817)

date_rng = pd.date_range('2013-01-01', '2016-01-01', freq='1H')
rain = random.choices([0,1], k=len(date_rng))
b = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(date_rng), 'rain':rain})

hour_rain = b.groupby([b.date.dt.month, b.date.dt.day, b.date.dt.hour])['rain'].agg([sum,np.size])
hour_rain.index.names = ['month','day','hour']

hour_rain.reset_index()

month   day hour    sum size
0   1   1   0   0   4
1   1   1   1   2   3
2   1   1   2   3   3
3   1   1   3   1   3
4   1   1   4   1   3
... ... ... ... ... ...
8755    12  31  19  2   3
8756    12  31  20  2   3
8757    12  31  21  2   3
8758    12  31  22  0   3
8759    12  31  23  0   3
```

Comment: I have corrected the code in your aggregate specifications.

Answer (score 0):

What I am trying to do it looks like something below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed(20200817)
date_rng = pd.date_range('2013-01-01', '2015-12-31', freq='1H')
rain = random.choices([0,1], k=len(date_rng))
b = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(date_rng), 'rain':rain})
b['year'] = b['date'].dt.year
b['month'] = b['date'].dt.month
b['day'] = b['date'].dt.day
b['hour'] = b['date'].dt.hour
b['X'] = b['date'].dt.strftime('%b')

b['hour']= b['hour'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
b['day']= b['day'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)


# Joint the Month, Date, Hour and Minute together
b['var'] = b['X']+b['day'].astype(str)+b['hour'].astype(str)


cols = b.columns.tolist()
cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]
b = b[cols]


# drop the unwanted columns
b = b.drop(["date","month","X","hour","day","year"], axis=1)


# now lets say I wanna predict 20 January 15.00 chance of rain

mask_x = (b['var']=='Jan2015')

mask_y = b['rain'].loc[mask_x]

mask_y.value_counts()

output:
0    2
1    1

# means the chance of rain is 33.33% and no chance of rain is 66.67%
```

When I do this with large datasets (more than 20 years) I feel it doesn't work very well.